# How do I match a pattern and then copy multiple lines?

Tags: awk, ksh

I have two files that I am working with.  The first file is a master database file that I am having to search through.  The second file is a file that I can make that allows me to name the items from the master database that I would like to pull out.  I have managed to make an AWK solution that will search the master database and extract the exact line that matches the second file.  However, I cannot figure out how to copy the lines after the match to my new file.

The master database looks something like this:

```
40005X/50005/60005/3/10/9/  
10038A/20038/30038/0/5/23./XXXX/
10039A/20039/30039/0/5/23./XXXX/
10040A/20040/30040/0/5/23./XXXX/
10041A/20041/30041/0/5/23./XXXX/
10042A/20042/30042/0/5/23./XXXX/
10043A/20043/30043/0/5/23./XXXX/
10044A/20044/30044/0/5/23./XXXX/
10045A/20045/30045/0/5/23./XXXX/
10046A/20046/30046/0/5/23./XXXX/
40006X/50006/60006/3/10/3/
10047A/20047/30047/0/5/23./XXXX/
10048A/20048/30048/0/5/23./XXXX/
10049A/20049/30049/0/5/23./XXXX/
40007X/50007/60007/3/10/3/
10050A/20050/30050/0/5/23./XXXX/
10051A/20051/30051/0/5/23./XXXX/
10052A/20052/30052/0/5/23./XXXX/
40008X/50008/60008/3/10/1/
10053A/20053/30053/0/5/23./XXXX/
40009X/50009/60009/3/10/3/
10054A/20054/30054/0/5/23./XXXX/
10055A/20055/30055/0/5/23./XXXX/
10056A/20056/30056/0/5/23./XXXX/
40010X/50010/60010/3/10/3/
10057A/20057/30057/0/5/23./XXXX/
10058A/20058/30058/0/5/23./XXXX/
10059A/20059/30059/0/5/23./XXXX/
```

In my example, the lines that start with 4000 is the first line that I am matching up to.  The last number in that row is what tells me how many lines there are to copy.  So in the first line, `40005X/50005/60005/3/10/9/`, I would be matching off of the 40005X, and the 9 in that line tells me that there are 9 lines underneath that I need to copy with it.

The second file is very simple and looks something like this:

```
40005X
40007X
40008X
```

As the script finds each match, I would like to move the information from the first file to a new file for analysis.  The end result would look like this:

```
40005X/50005/60005/3/10/9/
10038A/20038/30038/0/5/23./XXXX/
10039A/20039/30039/0/5/23./XXXX/
10040A/20040/30040/0/5/23./XXXX/
10041A/20041/30041/0/5/23./XXXX/
10042A/20042/30042/0/5/23./XXXX/
10043A/20043/30043/0/5/23./XXXX/
10044A/20044/30044/0/5/23./XXXX/
10045A/20045/30045/0/5/23./XXXX/
10046A/20046/30046/0/5/23./XXXX/
40007X/50007/60007/3/10/3/
10050A/20050/30050/0/5/23./XXXX/
10051A/20051/30051/0/5/23./XXXX/
10052A/20052/30052/0/5/23./XXXX/
40008X/50008/60008/3/10/1/
10053A/20053/30053/0/5/23./XXXX/
```

The code that I currently have that will match the first line is this:

```
#! /bin/ksh

file1=input_file
file2=input_masterdb
file3=output_test

awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR {id[$1]; next} $1 in id' $file1 $file2 > $file3
```

I have had the most success with AWK, however I am open to any suggestion.  However, I am working on this on a UNIX system.  I would like to keep it as a KSH script, since most of the other scripts that I use with this are written in that format, and I am most familiar with it.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your existing `awk` matches correctly the rows from the ids' file, you now need to add a condition to print N lines ahead after reading the last field of the matching row. So we will set a variable `p` to the number of lines to print plus one (the current one), and decrease per row printing.

```
awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{id[$0]; next} $1 in id{p=$6+1} p-->0{print}' file1 file2
```

or the same with last condition more "awkish" (by Ed Morton) and covering any possible extreme case of a huge file

```
awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{id[$0]; next} $1 in id{p=$6+1} p&&p--' file1 file2
```

here the `print` condition is omitted, as it is the default action, and the condition is true again as long as decreasing `p` is positive.

Answer (score 4):

another one

```
$ awk -F/ 'NR==FNR       {a[$1]; next} 
           !n && $1 in a {n=$(NF-1)+1} 
           n&&n--' file2 file1

40005X/50005/60005/3/10/9/
10038A/20038/30038/0/5/23./XXXX/
10039A/20039/30039/0/5/23./XXXX/
10040A/20040/30040/0/5/23./XXXX/
10041A/20041/30041/0/5/23./XXXX/
10042A/20042/30042/0/5/23./XXXX/
10043A/20043/30043/0/5/23./XXXX/
10044A/20044/30044/0/5/23./XXXX/
10045A/20045/30045/0/5/23./XXXX/
10046A/20046/30046/0/5/23./XXXX/
40007X/50007/60007/3/10/3/
10050A/20050/30050/0/5/23./XXXX/
10051A/20051/30051/0/5/23./XXXX/
10052A/20052/30052/0/5/23./XXXX/
40008X/50008/60008/3/10/1/
10053A/20053/30053/0/5/23./XXXX/
```

this takes care if any of the content lines match the ids given.  This will only look for another id after the specified number of lines printed.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Considering that you want to print lines from line which stars from digits X here. Where Input_file2 is file having only ids and Input_file1 is master file as per OP's question.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/ +$/,"")
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
/^[0-9]+X/{
  match($0,/[0-9]+\/$/)
  no_of_lines_to_print=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
  found=count=""
}
{
  if(count==no_of_lines_to_print){  count=found=""  }
  for(i in a){
    if(match($0,i)){
      found=1
      print
      next
    }
  }
}
found{
  ++count
}
count<=no_of_lines_to_print && count!=""
' Input_file2  Input_file1
```